MySQL Сортировка Varchar уникальных полей. Помогите исправить
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить запрос
SELECT *, MIN(cena) as min_price 
FROM table 
WHERE dir='123456' 
GROUP BY idtovar 
ORDER BY min1 ASC
       , min2 ASC
       , id DESC 
LIMIT 10

Я хочу получить min_price, а также уникальные idtovar отсортированные сначала min1 по возрастанию, затем  min2 по возрастанию, потом id по убыванию. Поля min1 и min2 являются varchar и могут быть пустыми или с целыми числами (min1 и min2 у группы одинаковые). Сейчас вывод неправильный, так как первыми идут пустые поля min1 и min2. Как их исключить? Спасибо.

А какой правильный, какой не правильный?

Из сортировки нужно исключить пустые поля min1 и min2

Ну вот у тебя есть группа с одинаковым idtovar, которая этим запросом сворачивается в одну строку. В группе три строки, и у всех разное min1. А теперь внимание, вопрос. Какое из этих трёх значений использовать при сортировке?

Извиняюсь, это не указал. min1 и min2 у группы одинаковые. Так что можно любое использовать.

min1 и min2 у группы одинаковые А это неважно. Либо поле включено в выражение группировки, либо обёрнуто агрегатной функцией. Если не так - запрос некорректен. И это касается всех трёх использованных в сортировке полей. Самое разумное - прочитайте внимательно тему Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? и выполните пункты 5 и 3. Пример данных должен включать все возможные комбинации фактов, а результат -  сопровождаться подробными пояснениями.

Вот я читал здесь ответы на английском - там люди пытаются помочь. Я второй раз задал вопрос на русском и вижу, что у нас могут только говорить. Неужели трудно если ты знаешь и понимаешь просто ответить? Вам поговорить не с кем? Зачем такой хороший проект флудом портить? Не хотите помочь - просто игнорируйте сообщения. Если хотите и знаете - помогите тем кто просит. Прошу не обижаться. Это не оскорбление.

Это очень сложный вопрос? Возможно, вариант CASE when min1 is null then 0 when min1 = '' then 0 END?

Решил вопрос так. Возможно есть решения лучше, но никто ничего не предложил:
SELECT *, MIN(cena) as min_price 
FROM table 
WHERE dir='123456' 
GROUP BY idtovar 
ORDER BY min1='' ASC
       , min2='' ASC
       ,min1 ASC, min2 ASC, id DESC 
LIMIT 10

